# C# прокси, поддерживающий авторизацию по сертификату

Tags: c#, proxy, x509certificate

У меня имеется rest self host  клиент на одной машине и сервер на другой. Авторизация используется по сертификату (httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCertificate());). При этом сервер принимает запросы только с определенных ip (self host клиент находится на машине с ip, которые сервер не принимает).
Задача: написать (очень желательно) или использовать готовый прокси, который бы находился на машине с разрешенным ip, через который бы шли запросы от клиента и который бы подменял ip запроса клиента на свой. Сертификат прокси не должен у себя хранить.
Подскажите пожалуйста варианты, как это сделать и куда копать?

Comment: а что уже пытались сделать?

Comment: Пробовал использовать TcpListener и TcpClient на самописном прокси - из одного соединения, инициируемого клиентом пробрасывать данные в другое соединение, открытое прокси к серверу.

Comment: Ещё пробовал настроить fiddler и ngix под windows. В итоге fidller требовал серт для коннекта, а ngix просто разрывал соединение с сервером